# Why every '<~~~>' is not replacing with color name? Why only last one is working?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$color='red';
 $lines=file("new.txt");
 foreach ($lines as $line) {
      if($line=='<~~~>'){
                  if($color=='red')
                     echo $color='yellow';
                  elseif($color=='yellow')
                     echo $color='red';
                    }
  else{
  echo $line."<br>";
    }
 }
?>
```

File Content:

> hey there how are you
>
> <~~~>
>
> I am fine What about you?
>
> <~~~>
>
> I am also good. thank you.
>
> <~~~>

Output is coming:

> hey there how are you
>
> <~~~>
>
> I am fine What about you?
>
> <~~~>
>
> I am also good. thank you.
>
> yellow

Comment: You're not replacing anything in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a trailing newline char at the end of each line. Use `trim($line)` to get rid of it :

```
<?php
$color = 'red';
$lines = file("new.txt");
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (trim($line) == '<~~~>') {
        if ($color == 'red')
            echo $color = 'yellow';
        else if ($color == 'yellow')
            echo $color = 'red';
        echo "<br />"; // Added to keep the original format
    } else {
        echo $line . "<br />";
    }
}
```

Output :

> hey there how are you
>
> yellow
>
> I am fine What about you?
>
> red
>
> I am also good. thank you.
>
> yellow

Answer (score 3):

It is explained in the [documentation of PHP `file()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

> **Return Values**
>
> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached.

This means, except for the last line, in case it doesn't end with a new line character, no line in your file can be equal to string `'<~~~>'`.

The solution(s) are also provided in the same [documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php), one paragraph below:

> **Note:**
>
> Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` is used, so you still need to use [`rtrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) if you do not want the line ending present.

Answer (score -3):

Your problem is

```
echo $color='yellow';
```

just do

```
echo 'yellow'
```

instead. Same goes for the echo 'red'

The expression "$color = 'yellow'" produces a return value of 'void' which then is seen by the "echo". So actually you're doing a "echo void;" equivalent.

Comment: Not true. The expression `$color = 'yellow'` gives a return value of 'yellow'. The statement `echo $color='yellow';` changes the value of `$color` and prints the new value out all at the same time.